# Can I speed up inference in PyTorch using autocast (automatic mixed precision)?

Tags: pytorch, nvidia, automatic-mixed-precision

The [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/amp_examples.html) (see also [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/automatic-mixed-precision)) for autocast in PyTorch only discuss training.  Does it speed things up if I also use autocast for inference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it could (may not in some cases though).

You are processing data with lower precision (e.g. `float16` vs `float32`).
Your program has to read and process less data in this case.

This might help with cache locality and hardware specific software (e.g. tensor cores if using CUDA)

Comment: In addition for a 2080TI isn't it also using faster tensor core units which would otherwise be unused?